# How to include each capital of multi-word surnames into abbreviations?

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I use alphabetic abbreviations in bibliography.
Some authors have surnames with multiple words, such as Eric Colin de Verdiere.
I write the entry as

```
author = {E. Colin de Verdiere and A. Schrijver}
```

and the output is `[dVS11]`. But I want my output as `[CVS11]`. How can I do this?

I tried using brackets `author = {E. {Colin de Verdiere} and A. Schrijver}` but nothing changed.

Comment: Have a look at `\DeclareLabelphaTemplate` in the biblatex manual. You will need to be using biber as the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on that particular output, you could use

```
shorthand = {CVS11}
```

on the entry in question, which is offered by [BibLaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Usually, you want one letter per person (and not per surname), which makes it also easier to estimate the number of authors in an alpha-fashioned style. Such an output would be `CS11`. It is achieved by:

```
author = {Colin de Verdiere, Eric and Schrijver, A.}
```